# How can I show $(1+4e^2)^{1/2}\approx 1+2e^2$ for $e<<1$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I tried using Taylor expansion, here's what I did: $$(1+4e^2)^{1/2}=1+\frac{4e^2}{(1+4e^2)^{1/2}}+...,$$ but I got nowhere from here. Are there any hints on how to solve it?

Comment: For $e \ll 1$? Isn't $e$ a fixed number? Or are you using $e$ as a variable? And your Taylor expansion is wrong.

Comment: So how can $e \ll 1$ if $e = 2.718 \dots$? Also, the Taylor expansion of $f = (1+x)^{1/2} = 1 + 1/2 \cdot x - 1/8 \cdot x^{2} \dots$

Comment: @Mattos, I was wrong. e is a variable, as Ian showed.

Comment: Binomial for all powers can be used

Answer (score 2):

For any $x>0$, $\sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac{x}{2}$ is trivial by squaring, but
$$ 1+\frac{x}{2}-\sqrt{1+x} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2-(1+x)}{1+\frac{x}{2}+\sqrt{1+x}}< \frac{x^2}{8\sqrt{1+x}} $$
hence
$$\boxed{\,1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8\sqrt{1+x}}< \sqrt{1+x}<1+\frac{x}{2}\,}$$
Now, just replace $x$ by $4e^2$.

Comment: funny approach! +1

Answer (score 1):

Writing $4e^2$ is more confusing than just writing $x$. The point is that you are expanding the function $(1+x)^{1/2}$ about $x=0$, and then plugging in $x=4\epsilon^2$. (I decline to use $e$ for this purpose because in standard notation $e$ is reserved for Euler's number, aka the base of the natural logarithm). Taylor expansion gives $1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)$, since $\left. \frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^{1/2} \right |_{x=0}=1/2.$